# Flash mesh tweening/animation

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, papervision3d, mesh

**Is there a way to correctly tween/animate meshes in Flash authoring tool?**

Shape tweens don't recognise movement of specific vertices, don't preserve connections and generally mess things up. Shape hints are too few for any non-trivial mesh, and too much manual labor anyway.

I am trying to accomplish smooth animation between two mesh shapes, but with all the points and vertices preserved, and no new points/vertices added.

Meshes in question are strictly 2D, but I won't mind if the solution called for Actionscript/Papervision3D assistance, although the authoring of keyframe mesh states needs to be done interactively in flash authoring tool (too complex shapes/movements to code them by hand).

*Ideas?*

Comment: could you show us a before/after shot?  if it's 2D vectors, then it probably looks like spaghetti in the middle, right?

Comment: Something like that. I have multiple surfaces (like countries on a map, for example). I'd like to tween them to a different configuration, but not to have them overlap, develop gaps and things like that during tweening.

Comment: Nope, shape hints is the best I could find, and that is of no use in any but most trivial of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the animation, bones might help. Though you need Flash CS4 to use them.
Their available from the standard toolbar.